# Return value of function that returns either base or derived clss pointer

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Given the relationship of classes shown in the code below:

```
class Base
{
    virtual getValue() { return 0; }
};
class Derived: public Base
{
    getValue() override { return 1; }
};
class Another
{
    Base* makeClass( bool );
    void createVector();
};
Base* Another::makeClass( bool base )
{
    if( base )
    {
        return new Base();
    }
    else
    {
        return new Derived();
    }
}
void Another::createVector()
{
     std::vector<Base> vector;
     vector.emplace( *makeClass( false ) );
     std::cout << vector[0].getValue();
}
```

Why does it print `0` instead of `1` ? 
Is it converting the `Derived*` into a `Base` when added to the vector?

Comment: Which virtual function of the objects were called? How was it declared? Please share the related code.

Comment: Please show the code calling makeClass, storing the response and accessing the virtual function.

Comment: When you return a base pointer it allows you to call functions in the Base class and if they are overloaded in derived, the overloaded function will be called instead

Comment: This code is technically correct, so the only way calling a method via a `Base*` pointer would exhibit `Base` class behavior is if the method in question is not `virtual` to begin with, or is not overwritten in `Derived`.

Comment: This was already a helpful comment, since it suggested that this function should be working as intendend (which it is).
The Issue was, that i stored it in a map as `Base` which caused the behavior. I changed that to `Base*` and now it works.

Comment: @loki General advice for posting questions at Stack Overflow: If it's about problems with specific code, post a [MCVE] that exactly can be used to reproduce the problem. Thank you for your attention. I'll be happy to retract my down and close vote if you consider to improve your post regarding [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/).

Comment: @user0042 I edited my question. Hope it became more clear this way.

Comment: @loki Possible duplicate of [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it converting the `Derived*` into a `Base` when added to the vector?" Yes.

In

```
vector.emplace( *makeClass( false ) );
```

`*makeClass( false )` dereferences the pointer returned and slices it into a `Base`. This `Base` is stored in the `vector`

Recommended reading: [What is object slicing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

To fix this,

```
 std::vector<Base *> vector; // but watch out for Cylons
 vector.emplace( makeClass( false ) );
 std::cout << vector[0]->getValue();
```

Or better, research `std::unique_ptr` and get smart pointer memory management working for you.